# I want to plot one value per two bars, on top of the two bars (treatment and control)

Tags: r

I want to plot one value per two bars, on top of the two bars (treatment and control), to indicate the percent change of the treatment group over control group. I am attaching a exemplary graph like which i need to plot graph for my data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you're trying to reproduce an existing graph, but that's not a great way to show this relationship.  Consider a scatter plot instead maybe? Eg (using the same data generator as @asd-tm in their answer)

```
df |> ggplot() + aes(obs1, obs2) + geom_point() + 
  coord_fixed() + 
  geom_abline() + 
  xlim(c(30,70)) + ylim(c(30,70)) + 
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label=sprintf("%s: %0.0f%%",obs_name,delta)))
```

[image]

Comment: A good idea actually +1. I would also advise OP to consider slope or dumbbell diagram. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = obs_name, y = value, fill = name), 
           data = df %>% 
             select (1:3) %>% 
             pivot_longer(-obs_name), 
           stat = "identity", 
           position = "dodge")+
  geom_text(aes(x = obs_name, y = pmax(obs1, obs2), label = paste0(format(delta, digits = 1), "%" )), 
            data = df, 
            vjust = -0.2)
```

[image]

Used data:

```
set.seed(50)
df <- 
  data.frame(obs_name = LETTERS[1:10],
           obs1 = rnorm(10, mean = 50, sd = 10),
           obs2 = rnorm(10, mean = 60, sd = 10)) %>% 
  mutate(delta = (obs2-obs1)/obs1 * 100)
```

Comment: If you use `pmax` instead of `max` you get the height of the labels to behave as you expect.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Thank you for your valueble comment. See the updated post

Comment: @asd-tm Thank you so much for your answer, it has saved lot of time for me in plotting the graphs

Comment: @asd-tm, we have run anova and tukey test for our data and we are getting bar graph with tukey test, how can we superimpose percent change over this graph

Comment: @asd-tm, how can i share you my data set and the code i used to get graph....

Comment: @ORBITTINGARYABHATA I guess it woulld be better to end with this question and start another one. I think that the specific issue stated here has already been solved and newer problems and ideas go beyond the namely stated question. About data. I advise you to buld a sample dataset (listing only the minimum required fields and rows). This dataset does not have to contain real data at all. The constructed `data.frame` / `tibble` etc. can (and even should) be posted in the body of your new question. You can use `dput()` to get the structure in text format.

Comment: @asd-tm As informed by you, i have posted this as another question, please do see and help me out.- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77094188/i-want-to-get-bar-graph-with-two-labels-in-r

Comment: @asd-tm I have accepted and upvoted your response for this question. Please do look at my another question and provide necessary help -

Comment: I think you accepted my answer by mistake.  I didn't really answer your question, just added some extra suggestion.  You can only accept one answer and it should be this one from @asd-tm

Comment: @GeorgeSavva I think that OP will not see your comment to my answer without at sign.  Were you going to write your comment under the question to make it visible by the OP? Anyway fortunately the question is over)))