# I want to get bar graph with two labels in r

Tags: r

I have plotted a bar graph for my data in r along with Tukey test values over it. But i also need to add another label as percent change between two treatments over each genotype of my graph. I am sharing the drive link for my sample data file and r code used to plot the graph. I am also sharing in it the graph we have got SL, but we need to get graph as it is in Picture 2( edited) in r itself. Please provide the code to do so. Thank you in advance.
[text](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d0eyrMUBszdouBjw7QraXGVws1YTvexL?usp=drive_link)
[image: This is graph what we have got in R]
[image: We need the graph like this with another label of Percent change for each genotype]

We tried getting graph in R, but we could get graph with only Tukey labels, we are unable to get another label which is percent change obtained between two treatments as seen in the images i have attached in this question.

Comment: Where do you get the values from? for example where did you get -50.16 from?

Comment: @Onyambu refer to attached files in drive link,  i have given the data i used to get this. Click on link - text

Comment: @Onyambu -50.16 is percent change in Stress compared to control in genotype G6.... and these values represent so on for all the genotypes, and i want to plot this value on graph which lies between both control and stress bars of each genotypes as shown in above picture

Comment: yes how did you calculate it from your data?

Comment: Can you show how you got the 50.16 from your data? There are 3 replicates. What formula did you use?

Comment: Yeah it is actually the mean value calculated from these replications. Formula for percent change = ((Control-Stress)/Control)*100.     If there is any way i can calculate this directly in R and then plot the same on graph would also be good for me

Comment: The values you have in your dataset do not match the ones on the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
# Import data
F2RBD <- readxl::read_excel("Data.xlsx")

# Run Model
anova <- aov(SL ~ Genotype*Treatment, data=F2RBD)
Tukey_summary <- F2RBD%>%
  mutate(across(-SL, ~factor(.x, unique(.x)))) %>%
  group_by(Treatment, Genotype) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(SL), sd = sd(SL), .groups = 'drop')%>%
  mutate(labels = c(round(diff(mean)/mean[1]*100,2), ''), .by=Genotype) %>%
  bind_cols(Tukey = multcompView::multcompLetters4(anova, TukeyHSD(anova))%>%
              getElement("Genotype:Treatment")%>%
              as.data.frame.list()%>%
              pull(Letters)%>%
              str_replace("(?<=.).+(?=.)", '-'))
```

---

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Tukey_summary, aes(Genotype, mean, fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9),
           color= "black", width=0.9, alpha=0.8) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Tukey, y = mean + sd), vjust = -0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 10/.pt)+
  geom_text(aes(label = labels, y = mean + sd),vjust = -2.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),size = 8/.pt, col = 'red')+
  # The main code ends here. The rest is lifted from your work
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,110))+
  scale_x_discrete(expand = 0:1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.25) + 
  labs(title = "", x = " ",  y = "Shoot length (cm)")+
  theme_bw()+ 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_text(face="bold", size = 14),
        aspect.ratio = 0.4, legend.position = c(0.94, 0.90),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", hjust = 1, 1, angle = 50, family = "calibri"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and suggestions, this id of great use for me and you saved a lot of time for me

Comment: how to maintain uniform decimals in percent change labels..... i need two decimals, but in some places it is 1 or 0 (-45 & -45.6), and also can i add percentage symbol for these values. It would be of great help if you can guide

Comment: @ORBITTINGARYABHATA instead of round, use `sprintf`

Comment: I am having few data traits that have duplicate values in them, and when i run them it is showing error, so how to overcomee it

Comment: @ORBITTINGARYABHATA there should be no error. duplicate has nothing to do with sprintf. Notice that you just change the round to sprintf. with the correct format. If round is working, sprintf must work also.

Comment: @ OnyambuThank you i will try this

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve two value labels by using two `geom_text()` layers and use different `nudge_y` values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |> 
  rownames_to_column() |> 
  ggplot(aes(rowname, mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = mpg), nudge_y = 1, size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = cyl), nudge_y = 2, size = 3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, angle = 50))
```

[image]